# Minifying and Including js and css files on Azure Project

Tags: msbuild, azure, minify, yui-compressor

I'm using YUI Compressor as a MsBuild Task on my Azure project. It works well on locally but when I try to publish it I cannot insert minified packages to my azure application package. Although I have tried a lot of things about package modifying on my .csproj file I couldn't work it out. How can I do this?

**Edit:**
My project is not a MVC or Webforms application. Just HTML and Javascript inside of an ASP.NET project. My problem is not minification. It is just placing minified external files in Azure Package when publishing it but if there is any other method that solves this azure problem, I can change YUI Compressor with ajaxmin or google closure... doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think modifying the service package is supported (you are also modifying the manifest). That's why I would look at it from an other perspective. I'm assuming you have such a setup:

> - Solution
>
>   - Empty ASP.NET Project
>
>     - Index.html
>     - App.js

Now, after you compile (and the MSBuild task runs) you'll have something like this:

> - Solution
>
>   - Empty ASP.NET Project
>
>     - Index.html
>     - App.js
>     - *App.min.js* (not included in the project, but available on the file system)

Now, buy simply including the App.min.js file in the project, it will be included in the service package when packaging or publishing your application. And besides that, the MSBuild tasks runs each time you compile, meaning the file will be updated before each time the application is packaged.

Comment: Yeah i did it like this. I'm also using tfs. When I check-in the file, MSBuild task returns an error about the locked file. Here the solution is: attrib -r  "$(TargetDir)..\View\js\bundle.js" :)

Comment: I'm assuming you might want to check in the file. By using attrib -r VS won't detect the pending change. I would advise to use an MSBuild task to check out the file first. MSBuild Tasks: http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/ or MSBuild Extension Pack: http://msbuildextensionpack.codeplex.com/

Comment: Yeah, it don't detect the pending change, that's what I want exactly. Because bundle.js is like a placeholder. Content is unnecessary. I just did an empty file check-in. :) Thanks for your advise. I will take a look to it.

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't specified about about whether it is WebForms or MVC, I would like to point out the out of the box support for the [bundling and minification](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/11/27/new-bundling-and-minification-support-asp-net-4-5-series.aspx) in [ASP.net MVC4](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2012/02/19/asp-net-mvc-4-beta.aspx). [Scott Gu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/) has explained it the MVC4 [preview demo](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2012/02/19/asp-net-mvc-4-beta.aspx).

You can also tweek it to work a way for that in ASP.net MVC3 too. Once this is achieved, you can achieve that in Azure as well.

Additional Articles :

- [ASP.NET MVC4 bundling in ASP.NET MVC3](http://jclaes.blogspot.com/2012/02/aspnet-mvc4-bundling-in-aspnet-mvc3.html)
- [New in ASP.NET MVC4: Bundling and Minification](http://www.beletsky.net/2012/04/new-in-aspnet-mvc4-bundling-and.html)

Comment: It isn't mvc or webforms. Just html and javascript in an asp.net project which works with an independent WCF REST service, so I have to use something like MSBuild.